# My Ps4 keeps deleting a game I've tried to install for months now

Tags: ps4, tera

I want to install Tera, and it's like 56gb. I download for some time then the next day it starts downloading from the beginning again. Like I download 20gb in a few days, but when a certain time comes, it starts all over again. This has been going on for 3 months now, cause I can never finish the download in that "certain" time. It never happens for updates though. Is it supposed to get deleted, and if yes after how long, or I'm having a problem?